# Update an Excel style in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel macro reads the answers to a survey from a set of Excel files. The answers of a survey contain a score (from 1 to 4) and a description. The goal is to generate a a matrix. Each cell of the matrix has a color that represents the score. I would like the user to be able to modify the layout of these cell. To make it easy to the user, I created a template matrix and a button. The user should be able to modify the layout of the cells and on a click of a button, a set of styles (Score 1, Score 2,...) should be generated. Once the matrix is created, the Workbook should be to function without the survey files.

I have tried a couple of things:

**Try 1**

```
ThisWorkbook.Styles.Add "Score 1", BasedOn:=cell1
```

This gives errors. I don't fully understand when they occur, but one of the causes is when the user modifies the cell layout by selecting another style.

**Try 2**

```
ThisWorkbook.Styles("Score 1").Delete
ThisWorkbook.Styles.Add "Score 1", BasedOn:=cell1
```

This is not a good idea: all cells loose their styling when it is executed a second time.

**Try 3: Current**

Copy the most frequently used properties of the cells layout and copy them to the style. If this style is deleted by the user, it is recreated. This procedures is not ideal, since most style properties won't be covered.

Is there a way to update a cell style that is more general? I would like there to be as little room as possible to make the workbook in an inconsistent and non-functional state.

Answer (score 0):

I sticked with try 3. Because it required a lot of code for all properties that seemed possible to be edited, and because of copying borders is tricky, I post the result.

```
'xR1_Template: the cell to base the style on
'nm_Style:    the name of the style
Public Function Upsert_Style(xR1_Template As Excel.Range, nm_Style As String) As Excel.Style
  
    Dim xStyle As Excel.Style
    Set xStyle = Fn.TryGet(ThisWorkbook.Styles, nm_Style)
    If Fn.IsNothing(xStyle) Then
        Set xStyle = ThisWorkbook.Styles.Add(nm_Style)
    End If

    xStyle.Font.Color = xR1_Template.Font.Color
    xStyle.Font.Bold = xR1_Template.Font.Bold
    xStyle.Font.Name = xR1_Template.Font.Name
    xStyle.Font.Italic = xR1_Template.Font.Italic
    xStyle.Font.Size = xR1_Template.Font.Size
    xStyle.Font.Strikethrough = xR1_Template.Font.Strikethrough
    xStyle.Font.Subscript = xR1_Template.Font.Subscript
    xStyle.Font.Superscript = xR1_Template.Font.Superscript

    xStyle.Font.Underline = xR1_Template.Font.Underline
    
    xStyle.Interior.Color = xR1_Template.Interior.Color
    xStyle.Interior.Pattern = xR1_Template.Interior.Pattern
    xStyle.Interior.PatternColor = xR1_Template.Interior.PatternColor

    'NOTE: necessary to delete all borders first. There's no way to delete them one by one.
    xStyle.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    
    Dim iBorder As Long
    For iBorder = 1 To xR1_Template.Borders.Count

       Dim xBorder As Excel.Border
       'NOTE:  The Borders property claims to work with xlBordersIndex argument, but this is not true.
    '       Normal indexing is used.
       Set xBorder = xR1_Template.Borders(iBorder)


       'NOTE:  "none-style" borders (=no border), should be skipped.
       '       Once they are retrieved using the Borders property, they are always visible.
       '       Setting them with xlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone does not hide them.
       If xBorder.LineStyle <> XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone Then

            Dim xBorder_Style As Excel.Border
            Set xBorder_Style = xStyle.Borders(iBorder)

            xBorder_Style.Color = xBorder.Color
            xBorder_Style.LineStyle = xBorder.LineStyle
            xBorder_Style.Weight = xBorder.Weight
            
        End If

    Next iBorder
    
    xStyle.AddIndent = xR1_Template.AddIndent
    xStyle.FormulaHidden = xR1_Template.FormulaHidden
    xStyle.HorizontalAlignment = xR1_Template.HorizontalAlignment
    xStyle.IndentLevel = xR1_Template.IndentLevel
    xStyle.NumberFormat = xR1_Template.NumberFormat
    xStyle.NumberFormatLocal = xR1_Template.NumberFormatLocal
    xStyle.Orientation = xR1_Template.Orientation
    xStyle.ShrinkToFit = xR1_Template.ShrinkToFit
    xStyle.VerticalAlignment = xR1_Template.VerticalAlignment
    xStyle.WrapText = xR1_Template.WrapText
    xStyle.IndentLevel = xR1_Template.IndentLevel

    Set Upsert_Style = xStyle
    
End Function
```